# How do I extract words between matching characters and combine them into new lines in awk/sed?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

any idea how I can remove all the formatting from these responses and preserve only the 'values' portion separated by comma?
I've achieved something similar but doing multiple runs and separate scripts.

```
response:
{
    type => 'query'
    timestamp => '1444304880'
    serial => '0000012970'
    address => '192.168.1.1'
    profile => 'common'
    query-id => '001'
    flags => '(NET, CORP)'
    version => '1.0.0.3'
}
response:
{
    type => 'query'
    timestamp => '1444305643'
    serial => '0000012971'
    address => '192.168.1.2'
    profile => 'common'
    query-id => '002'
    flags => '(CORP)'
    version => '1.0.0.3'
}
```

Ideal output:

```
query, 1444304880, 0000012970, 192.168.1.1, common, 001, (NET, CORP), 1.0.0.3
query, 1444305643, 0000012971, 192.168.1.2, common, 002, (CORP), 1.0.0.3
```

I noticed I can go two ways, first one is simply print out the $3 and $4 columns: awk '{print $3, $4}' dump.txt
That gives me:

```
'query'
'1444304880'
'0000012970'
'192.168.1.1'
```

But it also includes the spaces created by the '{ }' which I can eliminate. My other option is to go this way and take out the response {} section.

```
sed "s/\'//g" dump.txt | awk '/\{/{flag=1;next}/\}/{flag=0}flag'
```

But then I have to bring each line up using:

```
sed -e '/type/{N;s/\n//;}'
```

Any help in doing this in a nicer way is appreciated.

Comment: probably not a good idea to remove the quotes, if you want to use the output as a CSV file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk: uses "=>" as the field separator

```
awk -F "=>" '
    # a line with 2 fields, remove single quotes and print with a comma
    NF == 2 {gsub(/\x27/, "", $2); printf "%s,", $2}
    # end of record, overwrite the trailing command and add a newline
    $0 == "}" {printf "\b \n"}   
' file
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks I noticed that after I had used grep and cut unfortunately  after dumping over 1GB of data some responses contained more than 8 rows. This however does adjust regardless of how many rows you end up with. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep and paste:

```
grep -Po "=> '\K.*(?=')" file | paste -d , - - - - - - - -
```

Output:

```
query,1444304880,0000012970,192.168.1.1,common,001,(NET, CORP),1.0.0.3
query,1444305643,0000012971,192.168.1.2,common,002,(CORP),1.0.0.3
```

Comment: Thank you, however after generating a dump of the data it seemed like a lot of it had shifted due to some valid extra rows that seem to be part of the file every couple of thousands or so it would happen. Thanks for the quick response though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your input is structured as in your example, this should work:

```
cut -d '>' -f 2 foo.txt | grep "^ " | paste -d, - - - - - - - - | tr -d "'" | sed 's/^ //'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using `gnu-awk` and `FPAT`

```
awk -vFPAT="['][^\n]+[']" -vRS="{" -vOFS="," '
    NR>1{$1=$1; gsub(/\x27/,""); print}' file
```

you get,

```
query,1444304880,0000012970,192.168.1.1,common,001,(NET, CORP),1.0.0.3
query,1444305643,0000012971,192.168.1.2,common,002,(CORP),1.0.0.3
```